# Context initialization failed in alfresco community

Tags: maven, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I'm using alfresco community 5.0.d and suddenly I'm getting below error in catalina.out while logging in to http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/ where else http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco is not opening and showing page not found error (404).

Error in catalina.out is below

```
[localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' while setting bean property 'propertyEditorRegistrars' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'NamespaceService' while setting bean property 'namespaceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dictionaryDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantService' while setting bean property 'tenantService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantService' defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.0.d.jar!/alfresco/mt/mt-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantAdminDAO' while setting bean property 'tenantAdminDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantAdminDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/dao/dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectResourceLoader' while setting bean property 'resourceLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectResourceLoader' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'dialectClass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:674)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'NamespaceService' while setting bean property 'namespaceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dictionaryDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantService' while setting bean property 'tenantService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantService' defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.0.d.jar!/alfresco/mt/mt-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantAdminDAO' while setting bean property 'tenantAdminDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantAdminDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/dao/dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectResourceLoader' while setting bean property 'resourceLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectResourceLoader' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'dialectClass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dictionaryDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantService' while setting bean property 'tenantService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantService' defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.0.d.jar!/alfresco/mt/mt-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantAdminDAO' while setting bean property 'tenantAdminDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantAdminDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/dao/dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectResourceLoader' while setting bean property 'resourceLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectResourceLoader' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'dialectClass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantService' defined in URL [jar:file:/Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.0.d.jar!/alfresco/mt/mt-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantAdminDAO' while setting bean property 'tenantAdminDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantAdminDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/dao/dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectResourceLoader' while setting bean property 'resourceLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectResourceLoader' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'dialectClass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#755f08a' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 53 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of the log:

> Database connection failed: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
>   (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and
>   that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)

seems to indicate that your database is down or not reachable.

Use your db client to try to connect using the URL and credentials specified in alfresco-global.properties and that might shed light on what the problem is.

Comment: Got it fixed in alfresco-global.properties file, db was pointing to wrong port. Thanks!